# Possible to have separate src from modules and webpack config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have an app that is in a different folder structure than the modules installed from the package.json and I cannot find a way to make it work:

Structure:

- includes

  - build

    - build stuff
  - src

    - shared assets

      - js 
        ...APP (the app is a few folders down still)

How can I specify that the modules are somewhere and the app is in another place? Is this even possible? as If I set up the src of my app in the place where the build setup is, everything work as expected.

Where is my very simple webpack config.

```
var getters = require('./../gulpfile.js/config/getters');
var path = require('path');
var appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname, '../src');
var appRoot2 = path.resolve(__dirname,     '../../main/jcr_root/etc/designs/fit/includes/shared_assets/js/vueapps/chat_app/src');

module.exports = {
   context: appRoot2,
   entry: './main.js',
   output: {
       filename: 'app.js',
       path: getters.js.vue.apps.chatapp.dist
   },
   module: {
       loaders: [
           {
              test: /\.vue$/,
              loader: 'vue-loader',
              exclude: /node_modules/
           },
           {
              test: /\.js$/,
              loaders: 'babel-loader',
              exclude: /node_modules/
           }
       ]
   },
   resolve: {
       modules: [
          'node_modules'
       ]
   }
};
```

I this you can see I have **appRoot** and **appRoot2**, **appRoot** works as expected, **appRoot2** fails giving me this error.

**ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in ...**

EDIT: Forgot to mention I'm using :
"vue-loader": "^9.4.0".
"webpack": "^2.2.0".
"babel-loader": "^6.3.2".

EDIT2: Got it working, had to specify with another option:

```
 resolveLoader: {
    modules: [
        nodeRoot
    ],
 }
```

Also in the loader had to add this option:

```
 {
     test: /\.js$/,
     loaders: 'babel',
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     query: {
          presets: [nodeRoot + '/babel-preset-es2015'],
     }
 }
```

With the path to the preset.

Comment: Where is the webpack.config in your folder structure?

Comment: Inside the build folder, represented as **build stuff** in the bullet points.

Comment: I also have the same issues. Is there a way to do this?